# WPF OnPropertyChanged repeat code

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

New to WFP(MVVM), this seems to be the typical way to handle user changes:

```
private bool someProperty= false;
    public bool SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (someProperty!= value)
            {
                someProperty= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeProperty));


            }
        }
    }
```

For a big and complex screen with A LOT of fields which need editing, and handled right away (not at the end when clicking a button), this would result in a ton of sort of repeated code. Seems really hard to maintain, what if you have 50 or more properties? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The life saving technique here is to use [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) which injects `INotifyPropertyChanged` code into properties at compile time, and does some other even more clever stuff.

Comment: looks good. How would I use that to add some custom stuff for certain properties? Meaning that besides  OnPropertyChanged()  I want to execute some other specific code.

Comment: I think I found my own answer here: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/On_PropertyName_Changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the use it like this in each property:

```
private bool someProperty= false;
    public bool SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (someProperty!= value)
            {
                someProperty= value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My problem was with all 7-10 lines of code, I'd rather have just 1 or 2 for each property :)

Comment: @Keith Just use the `PropertyChanged.Fody` tool.

Answer (score 0):

I use a base class for all my viewmodels with these functions in it:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

protected bool SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, newValue))
    {
        return false;
    }
    backingField = newValue;
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

You can then use it this way from any subclass:

```
private string _firstName;

public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { SetValue(ref _firstName, value); }
}
```

`SetValue` will return `true` if the new value is different than the previous value, and `false` if it was the same, just in case you need to chain any further actions for more complex setters.